# Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0: Why is endpoints library not provided?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

With 1.0, we could just include 'endpoints' under 'libraries' in app.yaml.

```
libraries
  - name: endpoints
  - version: 1.0
```

However, for 2.0 we need to package it into vendored libraries. 
`"- version: 2.0"` won't work throws an error, `endpoints version "2.0" is not supported, use one of: "1.0"`

Why was this seemingly regressive change made?